# jquery loop adding twice

Tags: jquery, css

When running this code, every time I click the '#right', the #slide gets incremented by 2 instead of just 1... so for example i get the 1st, 3rd and the 5th elements if there are a total 6 elements.

```
    var present=2;
    var total_slide=document.getElementById("slider").childElementCount;
    $("#right").click(function()
    {

        for(i=1;i<=total_slide;i++) {
            $("#slide"+i).css("display","none"); // hide all elements
        }
        $('#slide'+present).css("display","block"); // the problem : display 
                                                    // only the present element
                                                    // (gets incremented by 2 )
        present=(present+1)%total_slide;
    });
```

If however i use 1,2,3 etc for eg: ('#slide'+2) in place of ('#slide'+present), get the right results, but i wanna do this dynamically ..

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to do a for loop, jQuery returns already a collection of your elements in array.

You just need to pre-increment and 'modulize' (`%`) your counter.

http://jsbin.com/uhiyew/1/edit

```
var present=2;
var $childrens = $("#slider > *");
var total_slide = $childrens.length;

$childrens.eq(present).show();


$("#right").click(function(){

     $childrens.hide() // hide all elements
        .eq(++present%total_slide).show(); // show desired

});
```

Comment: this isn't working perfectly either ..var present = 1;
var $childrens = $("#slider > *");
var total_slide = $childrens.length;
$childrens.hide();
$childrens.eq(present).show();

$("#right").click(function(){

     $childrens.hide() // hide all elements
        .eq(++present%total_slide).show(); // show desired


}); ..  its following this order : 2,4,1,3,5,2

Comment: and in the case of even number of slides .. it goes 2 4 2 4 .. so its still jumping twice :(

Comment: @btheceo than you need to show your HTML, looks like some other elements inside your `#slide` are messing with the index count.

Comment: <div id="slider">

<?php
$gal = get_post_meta($post->ID,'gal',true);
$attachments = explode(',', $gal);
$j=0;

 

 foreach ( $attachments as $attachment) { $j=$j+1;?>
 
 
 
 
<div id="slide<?php echo $j?>" class="slide" align="center">
    <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment, 'full' );?>
    
</div>
 
 
 <?php 
  
 
}
?>
</div>

Comment: this is the html .. its a wordpress document .. i tried to print the value of present everytime and it was going 1 3 5 and so on .. for now i have worked around it by incrementing .5 everytime .. so the problems solved but would still like to understand why its happening .. though your solution i think was perfect :D

Comment: @btheceo What you posted is PHP, not pure HTML, you can always take a look at the returned HTML (returned by PHP) by inspecting your element in developer tools (console).